# How to count number of lines in a textbox in C# GUI

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and want to count number of lines in a C# textbox. I have tried Textbox.Lines.Count but it is not working as "Lines" is no more available in 2010.Is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 1):

Try use

```
var count = Textbox.Lines.Length;
```

[More detail here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.100).aspx)

Or try this:

```
 string[] tmpArray = textBox1.Lines;
 int count =  tmpArray.Length;
```

Comment: Well as I mentioned "Textbox.Lines.Length" is no more avalable in visual studio 2010 thus I tried:

Comment: I don't have VS 2010 and so I can not check this. Try new version in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int first = 0;
int last = 0;
count=0;`enter code here`
last = textBox.GetLastVisibleLineIndex();
count++;
while (first <= last)
{
String dummy = textBox.GetLineText(first);
if (dummy.Contains("\n") || dummy.Contains("\r") || dummy.Contains("\r\n"))
{
dummy = dummy.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
count++;
}
first++;
}
```